# Проблема с шаблонами Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс, mobile

У сайта есть 2 шаблона, под десктоп и под мобильную версию. И в зависимости от устройства надо выводить нужный.
Я делаю так, у сайта определил 2 шаблона, сначала мобильный с условием (`siteType=='pda'`), затем обычный. В файле `init.php` делаю проверку

```
$mobi = new \Olepro\Classes\Helpers\MobileDetect();
if($mobi->isMobile() && !isset($_COOKIE['siteType']) && !$_GET['type'])
{
    LocalRedirect("/?type=pda");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['type']))
{
    switch ($_GET['type'])
    {
        case 'pda':
            setcookie('siteType', 'pda', time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, '/');
            define('siteType', 'pda');
            break;
        default:
            setcookie('siteType', 'original', time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, '/');
            define('siteType', 'original');
    }
} else
{
    $checkType = '';
    if (isset($_COOKIE['siteType']))
        $checkType = $_COOKIE['siteType'];
    switch ($checkType)
    {
        case 'pda':
            define('siteType', 'pda');
            break;
        default:
            define('siteType', '');
    }
}
```

Но срабатывает это через раз. Т.е. заходишь на сайт с мобильного, открывается версия `desktop`, обновляешь страницу мобильная версия появляется. Заходишь обратно, может появиться или мобильная или десктопная версия, как повезет. Я так подозреваю, что это какой то косяк с кешом, но точно не уверен. Никогда с битрикс не работал

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть в том, что в init.php ещё нет переменных сессии. Сессия открывается после того, как отработает init. Порядок выполнения страницы смотрите здесь: http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/pageplan.php

По крайней мере, писать в куки смысла нет. Советую для этого использовать событие
onBeforeProlog
http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onbeforeprolog.php

Comment: да, я так и переделал подписываю функцию на onBeforeProlog . указываю там напрямую значение константы SITE_TEMPLATE_ID на всякий и все равно когда как шаблон выводиться, когда мобильный, когда десктопный

Comment: Ну тут уже нужно проверять, устанавливается ли константа. И далее сужать круг, чтобы понять в чём именно проблема.

Comment: А кстати, зачем такая сложная схема? гет параметры, куки, библиотека.. Если у вас MobileDetect всё верно определяет, почему бы не пользоваться только ей?

Comment: Что бы была возможность переключиться на любой шаблон и пользоваться им. А кеш не сохраняет страницу вместе с шаблоном?

Answer (score 0):

1. Рекомендую немного поменять сам по себе исходный код.
   `if (!isset($_COOKIE['siteType']) && !$_GET['type']) {
       $mobi = new \Olepro\Classes\Helpers\MobileDetect();
       if ($mobi->isMobile()) {
           LocalRedirect("/?type=pda");
           exit;
       }
   }
   $isMobile = false;
   if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
       setcookie(
           'siteType', 
           ( $isMobile = $_GET['type'] == 'pda') ? 'pda' : 'original', 
           time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, 
           '/'
       );
   } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['siteType'])) {
       $isMobile = $_COOKIE['siteType'] == 'pda';
   }
   if ($isMobile) {
       define('siteType', 'pda');
   } else {
       define('siteType', '');
   }`
2. Попробуйте его. В вашем коде есть неоднозначный `define` то в `''`, то в `'original'`, и проверки несколько запутанные.
3. Если не заработает, то покажите еще скриншот настроек шаблонов для сайта.

Comment: Проблема в том что даже если вместо всего этого кода поставить просто define('siteType', 'pda'); то отображается не тот шаблон на некоторых страницах. http://c2n.me/3qBhAKl